# Java - How to keep a live socket connection

Tags: java

Ok guys im not that experienced so take it easy on me.

Ok so i have 2 programs, one for the server (my pc) and one for the client(other pcs)
and this is the setup

server listens/accepts > client connects > server sends command to client > client executes.

and thats it, after that it disconnects BUT i need the client to stay connected so the server can keep sending commands as needed.

How can i achieve this?

I can provide more info if need just ask!
thanks for all the help guys.

Comment: This begs the question, why disconnect at all?

Comment: As long as you keep references to the opened sockets, the connection should stay open. (Baring any network failures.)

Answer (score 8):

The server will receive a socket when accept() returns, and as long as that socket does not get closed then the connection remains open. The client will then run in a loop of read/execute-command until the server closes the connection. I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: yes i tryed running some sort of loop in another thread to keep the connection alive but since that that thread is busy looping it cant break out to read commands.

Comment: i will provide code to help in alittle bit. just wait till i do then respond with you answer.

Comment: the loop on the client side isn't to keep the connection alive, its just to read/write from/to the socket...java's serversocket/socket classes are TCP/IP sockets so they wont disconnect until you say disconnect

Answer (score 0):

There's a few official examples to get you started with [Java sockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html). Plus since its Java, getting this setup is pretty easy.

As Kevin already said, you'll open up a ServerSocket on some open port. Then call accept() which will return when a client connects with a Socket on the same port as the ServerSocket.

Also, make sure you pay attention to the specified host if you want the client program to connect from a computer different from the host. You might run into trouble with the loopback interface if you specify the host as "null" or "127.0.0.1".